# how to solve unparseable date ""

Tags: java, parsing

I am gonna ask you guys something I give on to :( I want to parse 56 atribute seperated by tab on each row to database but when I run, there is error:

> 12:39:12,452 INFO  [com.daksa.jsfconsolidated.beans.FetchBean] (default task-3) Masuk Fungsi Fetch Data Controller
> 12:39:12,454 INFO  [com.daksa.jsfconsolidated.beans.FetchBean] (default task-3) DATA KE : 1
> 12:39:12,455 SEVERE [com.daksa.jsfconsolidated.beans.FetchBean] (default task-3) null: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
> at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:395)
> at deployment.Consolidated-JSF-0.war//com.daksa.jsfconsolidated.beans.FetchBean.save(FetchBean.java:225)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at javax.el.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:245)

Here is my code especially on FetchBean:225 (dataWork)

```
try {
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/fetchfile/nasabah"));
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        String lineJustFetched = null;
        String[] wordsArray;
        int iterasi = 1;
        while (true) {
            lineJustFetched = buf.readLine();
            if (lineJustFetched == null) {
                break;
            } else {
                wordsArray = lineJustFetched.split("\t");
                for (String each : wordsArray) {
                    words.add(each);
                    if (iterasi % 55 == 0) {
                        LOG.info("DATA KE : {}", iterasi / 55);

                        
                        Date reportDate = format.parse(words.get(0));
                        Date birthDate = format.parse(words.get(19));
                        Date dateWork = format.parse(words.get(28));
                        
                        nasabahModel.setReportDate(reportDate);
                        nasabahModel.setCustomerInformationNumber(words.get(1));
                        nasabahModel.setCustomerName(words.get(2));
                        .........
                        nasabahModel.setCompanyName(words.get(27));
                        nasabahModel.setDateOfWork(dateWork);
                        ...........
                        words.clear();
                    }
                    iterasi++;
                }
            }
            controller.addNasabah(nasabahModel);
        }
        buf.close();
        LOG.info("Nasabah READ AND SAVE : DONE");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FetchBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Please, I need you guys help, I hope I will find the good answer here, thanks and good days^^

Comment: Well it sounds like that field is empty. You need to work out why it's empty, and how you want to handle that situation.

Comment: One of the inputs to `format.parse` is an empty string. That's not a valid date. You'll have to see which one it is (we don't know which line is 225 in your code sample) and figure out **why** it's the empty string. Maybe you need to treat the empty string as a `null` Date?

Comment: yes, it is. dateWork is an atribute but there is a lot empty records. do you have any idea with my code how to skip those empty record? thanks in advanced

Comment: A quick fix would be to make a method, `Date parseOrNull(String s)` Then in the method either validate the string, or `try{ return format.parse(s); } catch(ParseException e){ return null; }` maybe you don't want null dates though so you have to decide what to do if the data is invalid.